# how to use vim to delete one of the commas &the word nearby in a long string(use REGEX)

Tags: regex, vim

Like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

How to delete the comma between `4` & `5`

I use the REGEX like this in vim but it could not work:

```
:s/\,(?=(.*?,){2})(?!((.*?,){2}).*,)//
```

Please show the right answer. 
thanks

Comment: Try `:s/\(4\)\@<=,\(5\)\@=//`. Or given your current requirements, you can just replace `4,5` with `45`.

Comment: no,is not the point about 4or5, it maybe different kinds of long strings,it's the point about the last but two in all commas,and it's also not the point about one comma,mybe lots of sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's regular expression dialect is different from PCRE (what you seem to be using). In particular:

- non-greedy quantifier is `\{-}`, not `*?`
- grouping via `(...)` must be escaped: `\(...\)` (unless you switch to *verbose mode* with `\v`)
- positive lookahead is `\(...\)\@=`, not `(?=...)`
- negative lookahead is `\(...\)\@!`, not `(?!...)`

With these transformations (cp. `:help perl-patterns`), you'll arrive at this working regexp:

```
:s/,\(\(.\{-},\)\{2}\)\@=\(\(\(.\{-},\)\{2}\).*,\)\@!//
```

<sup>Of course, also in Vim there's *more than one way to do it.*</sup>

If you breathe and live PCRE regexps, you can use an embedded Perl interpreter (if enabled in your Vim build) via `:perldo s/.../...`

Comment: so ga,it's diverse dimensions.No wander i think why it could not work.thanks it's helpful

Comment: Right, unfortunately, there's no single regexp standard :-( If this answers your question, please accept it by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!

Comment: OK,i found it.if it's really right,i'll give the check